# Rolling counter for 24 hours timestamp - pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Following is the input dataframe:

```
id,timestamp            
1,1/10/18 17:57
1,1/12/18 13:29
1,2/1/18 11:04
1,2/14/18 10:53
1,3/7/18 11:16
1,3/19/18 8:45
1,3/19/18 12:44
1,3/30/18 23:45
1,4/15/18 19:54
1,4/15/18 19:54
1,4/15/18 19:54
1,7/9/18 19:26
1,7/9/18 19:26
1,7/10/18 6:03
1,7/10/18 9:03
```

I need to create another column "counter" with counter increasing if previous row is within 24 hours timestamp. Counter should reset to 0 if it is not within 24 hours. For above input , desired output is:

```
id,timestamp,counter        
1,1/10/18 17:57,0
1,1/12/18 13:29,0
1,2/1/18 11:04,0
1,2/14/18 10:53,0
1,3/7/18 11:16,0
1,3/19/18 8:45,0
1,3/19/18 12:44,1
1,3/30/18 23:45,0
1,4/15/18 19:54,0
1,4/15/18 19:54,1
1,4/15/18 19:54,2
1,7/9/18 19:26,0
1,7/9/18 19:26,1
1,7/10/18 6:03,2
1,7/10/18 9:03,3
```

I have been able to solve the problem using following code , where :

1. I am first using lag to find previous value.
2. Calculating the difference in hours and checking if it is within 24 hours and create a flag.
3. Using to_date from lag timestamp if flag is 1 else     to_date(timestamp).
4. Using row_number and partition by id,flag to get the counter value.

Logic works fine except for last row in output , it is because i am picking to_date from lag which seems incorrect. I assume i need to group the dataframe but i am unable to proceed. Any help is appreciated.

```
    test_1=df.withColumn("timestamp",to_timestamp(col("timestamp"),'MM/dd/yy HH:mm'))
newdf = test_1.withColumn("lag",lag(col("timestamp"),1).over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("timestamp")))
    df2 = (
        newdf.withColumn('lag',col('lag'))\
        .withColumn('timestamp',col('timestamp'))\
        .withColumn('DiffInSeconds',col('timestamp').cast("long")-col("lag").cast("long")))
    df3 = df2.withColumn('DiffInHours',round(col('DiffInSeconds')/3600)).drop("DiffInSeconds")
    df5 = df3.withColumn("flaglag", when((col("DiffInHours") >= 0 ) & (col("DiffInHours") <= 24 ),0).otherwise(1))
    df6=df5.withColumn("to_date", when(col("flaglag") == 1,to_date('timestamp')).otherwise(to_date('lag')))
    nw_win=Window.partitionBy("id","to_date").orderBy("timestamp")
    final_df=df6.withColumn("counter",row_number().over(nw_win)-1)
```

Comment: Not an answer but you can sequence transformations. That way you don't have to create a new variable for each transformation. Unless of course there's a specific reason you want to keep track of intermediate dataframes you can try something like:
`transformed_df = df.withColumn(...).withColumn(...)...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by creating a group number column.

```
tmp_join = final_df.withColumn("group", sum(when(col("flaglag") == 0,0).otherwise(1)).over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("timestamp")))
final_new_df = tmp_join.withColumn("C", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("id","group").orderBy("timestamp"))-1)
```